# Forecast interval for VAR model predictions

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, prediction-interval

I have been looking at VAR models for doing multivariate time series analysis. What would one need to do to also estimate forecast intervals for the predictions from a VAR model?

Comment: These are called *forecast intervals* or *prediction intervals*, not *confidence intervals*.

Comment: ... see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info for the difference.

Comment: @RichardHardy, Stephan Thanks for clarifying that up! So, any ideas? :)

Comment: Have you tried a textbook, e.g. Lutkepohl's ["New Introduction to Multivariate Time Series Analysis"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401728)?